# A new major version is available for Algolia

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

every time I install a new react-native application I am getting this message

```
A new major version is available for Algolia! Please now use the https://rubygems.org/gems/algolia gem to get the latest features.
```

what I tried.

I try to update every thing with pod update but this not working.
I also try to install latest cocoa pods but this also not working.

how can I update Algolia!. I am new to iOS development